# & (ampersand) symbol is not coming in GET parameter value in php page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php page with following components. Onclick the GET value should display in Textbox

**JavaScript**

```
category= Biscuits & Creams
document.location.href= "page.php?category="+category;
```

**On Load GET parameter is Coming as follows,**

> ```
> page.php?category=Biscuits%20&%20Creams
> ```

**Display the value in php page:**

```
<input type="text" Value="<?php echo urlencode($_GET['category']);?>"/>
```

Output in Text Box is coming as

> **Biscuits** instead of **Biscuits & Creams**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add encode method in javascript, and in php use `urldecode` instead of `urlencode`

Javascript:

```
 category= 'Biscuits & Creams';
 document.location.href= "page.php?category="+encodeURIComponent(category);
```

Answer (score 3):

The PHP engine is using the `&` to separate the parameters in the query string. [Encode it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript) before using it in a URL.